# Outlook 2010 sync issue Error with Send/Receive 80041004

Tags: windows, email, outlook, synchronization, mapi

It works well before a period of time but stopped working for three or four months, and I have searched a lot for a solution to this problem on the Internet and found many ways but my problem is not solved yet.

I setup my Email using Hotmail Connector

May someone help me to solve this issue please, Why Outlook stopped working ?

Here's the Synchronization Log

```
10:13:03 Synchronizer Version 14.0.6123
10:13:03 Synchronizing Mailbox '-----@hotmail.com'
10:13:03 Synchronizing Hierarchy
10:13:03       4 folder(s) added to online store
10:13:03       1 folder(s) updated in online store
10:13:03 Synchronizing local changes in folder 'Calendar'
10:13:03 Synchronizing local changes in folder 'Contacts'
10:13:03 Synchronizing local changes in folder 'Inbox'
10:13:03 Error synchronizing folder
10:13:03         [80041004-0-0-430]
10:13:03 Error with Send/Receive.
10:13:03 There was an error synchronizing your folder hierarchy. Error : 80041004.
10:13:03 Synchronizing server changes in folder 'Calendar'
10:13:03 Synchronizing server changes in folder 'Contacts'
10:13:05 

*******************
10:13:05 

*Request*       
10:13:05 10:13:03:0845


10:13:05 POST
10:13:05  http://
10:13:05 contacts.msn.com
10:13:05 /ABService/ABService.asmx
10:13:05 


10:13:05 <ABFindAll xmlns="http://www.msn.com/webservices/AddressBook"> <abId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</abId><abView>Full</abView><deltasOnly>false</deltasOnly></ABFindAll>
10:13:05 

*Response*  
10:13:05 10:13:05:0546


10:13:05 HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Cache-Control: private

Content-Length: 419

Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

Content-Encoding: gzip

Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains

X-MSNSERVER: CO1CDP1011915

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

Date: Mon, 15 Jan 2018 06:13:03 GMT




10:13:05 


10:13:05 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Invalid Application Header  Application ID is either not defined in database or blocked from access.</faultstring><faultactor>http://www.msn.com/webservices/AddressBook/ABFindAll</faultactor><detail><errorcode xmlns="http://w
10:13:05 

*******************
10:13:05 Error with Send/Receive.
10:13:05 There was an error synchronizing a contacts folder. Error : 80041216.
10:13:05 Synchronizing server changes in folder 'Drafts'
10:13:05 Synchronizing local changes in folder 'Inbox'
10:13:05 Error synchronizing folder
10:13:05         [80041004-0-0-430]
10:13:05 Synchronizing server changes in folder 'Sent Items'
10:13:05 Synchronizing server changes in folder 'Deleted Items'
10:13:05 Synchronizing server changes in folder 'Junk E-mail'
10:13:05 Done
10:13:06 

*******************
10:13:06 

*Request*       
10:13:06 10:13:05:0583


10:13:06 POST
10:13:06  http://
10:13:06 mail.services.live.com
10:13:06 /DeltaSync_v2.0.0/Settings.aspx
10:13:06 


10:13:06 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Settings xmlns="HMSETTINGS:"><ServiceSettings><SafetySchemaVersion>1</SafetySchemaVersion><SafetyLevelRules><GetVersion/></SafetyLevelRules><SafetyActions><GetVersion/></SafetyActions><Properties><Get/></Properties></ServiceSettings><AccountSettings><Get><Options/><Properties/></Get></AccountSettings></Settings>
10:13:06 

*Response*  
10:13:06 00:00:00:0000


10:13:06 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connected the email using manually configure the server using Hotmail connector then checked the Income and outcome servers with default hotmail servers